# Is it ok to say "good morning" at anytime?

Tags: phrase-usage

A friend of mine told me that you can say "*good morning*" to a person at any time, if you are seeing him/her for the first time on that day. Is this true?

Comment: You *can* say good morning any time you want, but people will think you're being silly, or they'll point out it's not actually morning.  That's fine with me, so I personally say good morning any time I feel like it :-)

Comment: There's room for a little leeway here. If someone wished me a "Good morning" on our first meeting of the day, and it was still before 1 o'clock, I wouldn't think much of it, and I'd probably just figure that they weren't completely aware of the time. Hearing it at 5:30 PM might get more of an odd look, though (unless maybe we were both just starting a shift at work).

Comment: AH., it's not common and is likely to cause others to point out it's not actually morning, as snailplane mentioned.

Comment: When we have Good afternoon, good evening and hi, hello kind of greetings then why say Good morning even if we see the person first time in the day. Its okay for fun to tease a friend but I dont think otherwise in social and official circumstances

Comment: It is decidedly strange to say 'good morning' in the United States if it is no longer the morning. People saying otherwise maybe are focusing on different locations. It might be used as a **joke** to say it after noon (as someone else remarked), but it would not be used normally.

Comment: In Australia you'd only say "good morning" (a) if it actually is morning, (b) if you've not yet realised it's actually afternoon, or (c) ironically, if someone was expected in the morning but arrived after noon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps that is a regional thing; where I am from in Canada, we laugh at each other good-naturedly if we say "*good morning*" after 12:00 noon, as if we slept in late.

If it is approaching 12:00 noon, we will look at our watches first to make sure we shouldn't say "*good afternoon*" instead.

Likewise, we will say "*good evening*" as a greeting after around 6:00 p.m., and "*good night*" when parting.

Comment: In the UK, _Good Afternoon_ is possible between noon and 6:00 p.m., but a simple _Hello_ is more usual. _Good day_ is not so very common here, and in the past was dismissive, as in _Then I wish you good day, sir._

Comment: I agree; it is more common for me to say "_hello_" or "_hi_" to people more than anything else, and "_good day_" is a little archaic, unless spoken as slang such as "_g'day_".

Comment: The US has the same "you're not a morning person, are you?" reaction to "good morning" said after 12:00 pm.

Comment: @TrishRempel: Can I say "Good Day" at night?

Comment: It is better to write 12 p.m. in lower case. Or better 12 noon, which is less ambiguous.

Comment: @DipakYadav Where I am, the slang _g'day_ is more common, and I've heard it at all times of the day, even in the evening.

Comment: @QuentinUK I'm curious, do you have a reference that states whether the a.m. or AM format is preferred, or is it a regional preference? In all my business correspondence here, we use the capital version without periods. I'm also curious how 12 noon is less ambiguous than 12:00 PM - they mean the same thing; in fact, just "noon" would work as well.

Comment: @Trish Rempel http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22784/am-pm-vs-a-m-p-m-vs-am-pm

Comment: @Trish Rempel http://www.npl.co.uk/science-technology/time-frequency/time/faqs/is-midnight-12-a.m.-or-12-p.m.-(faq-time), yes noon is just as good but if you've just said "after" it sounds like "afternoon".

Comment: @QuentinUK I updated my response as per your time abbreviation suggestion, and took out _good day_ as a suggestion because it isn't as common.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with most of the part of Trish's answer. A little yet good information.

> Greet anyone *Good Morning* when you seem them **first time for that day!** This could be little beyond noon as well!

Nevertheless, avoid this when it is obvious to say *Good evening.*

Comment: What is your source for that quote? Because that assertion is precisely what the OP is asking about, and what most of us are disagreeing with. (To be explicit, no, you ***can't*** say "Good Morning" just because it's the first time you're seeing someone that day. Your quoted assertion is ***not true***.)

Comment: @Martha Well, there is no concrete evidence for everything especially for the language we use day-to-day. On this question only, J.R. stated in his comment and has got 4 votes up! As I said, this could be **little** beyond noon (Afternoon). But then one should understand and avoid it if it's not **obvious** morning (as 1700 hr). **Maybe,** this is common as we greet mainly during *pre-lunch* (1 pm?) office hours. Similarly, we greet with *Good evening* even though meeting someone at 2000 hr. Right?

Comment: Maulik, that's all well and nice, but you used blockquote formatting for the statement. That implies that it's a, well, *quote*, as in someone else said it. If that is the case, you need to provide the *source* for the quote, otherwise we can't evaluate its validity. (And if it's not a quote, for heaven's sake, don't format it like one!)

Comment: Sometimes you might hear it used late in the day (with good-natured jocularity), if, say, the two people are coworkers who happen to work a night shift together.