# From what hour can "good afternoon" be said?

Tags: spoken-english

From what hour can "good afternoon" be said, is it acceptable to say it from around 12:00 o'clock?

Comment: In England good afternoon is only used after around 13:00. Any time from 12:00 until 13:00 is often conveyed with a sarcastic intent.

Comment: As a US English speaker, I would say it any time after noon.

Comment: @stangdon it seems to be dependent in individual dialect. Do you know of any of these style differences? One that would pop into my head would be how English people refer from midnight until 5AM night.

Comment: @fishyninja1 - I agree that it seems to be very locally dependent.  I don't have a good reference for the differences, though - I just know what I would say and what people around me say!

Comment: I have been greeted with "good afternoon" shortly after 12 o'clock (and thought nothing of it). It is, after all, "after" noon. I have also been greeted with the same phrase before 12 o'clock (when I've turned up late for work) but that is another matter.

Comment: @fishyninja: apologies, but my experience in the UK is different. I would always use Good Afternoon after, literally, noon. What else could I say? Surely not Good Morning. The sarcastic use of Good Afternoon applies usually in the morning when someone arrives later for work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok to say "good morning" at anytime?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/is-it-ok-to-say-good-morning-at-anytime)

Comment: @fishyninja1, you say that English people refer to the time between midnight until 5AM as night: that's because it **is** night. Night is defined as "the part of every 24-hour period when it is dark because there is very little light from the sun". http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/night

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned the the comments, it can vary by region and even personal taste.  However since English lacks a commonly-used "good day" greeting, we've only the choice between "good morning", "good afternoon", and "good evening".

Logically, I split the day into three parts:

1. The time from when I get up until around noon (good morning)
2. From noon until it gets (relatively) dark (good afternoon)
3. From dusk until I go to bed (good evening).

If someone were to wish me "good morning" and I saw the time was 12:01, I would respond, "Don't you mean 'good afternoon'?".  In the same way, if I meet up with someone at 2am I would say "good morning" even if I didn't know whether or not they'd been to bed, because *I'm* now awake.

The line between afternoon and evening is also personal preference.  If someone said to me "good evening" and the sun was still up, I might reply with, "Is it that late already?"

This leaves a fuzzy area between midnight and sunrise.  Again, if I'd been to bed and got up very early, I'd still say "good morning" because it's "morning" to me -- but if I'd stayed up all night, I might still wish someone "good morning" because it *feels* early rather than late.  But that could be a discussion for another post.