# a morning greeting: is it "morning", "g'morning" or neither?

Tags: expressions

Not a native English speaker and poor at distinguishing shortened expressions, I am not sure if native English speakers indeed say "Morning", or "G'morning", in addition to the formal expression "GOOD (accented) morning" or "(plain vanilla) good morning".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer:

The *correct*, formal greeting is "*Good morning*".

(provided the current time of day *is* morning, then it would become "*good afternoon*")

Any other variation is casual, or colloquial speech. There are also differences between the way the greeting may be said in different regional accents, and between British, American, Australian, and other native English speaking countries.

In British English it is common to simply say "morning!" as a shortened version of this greeting, and likely is in other countries too.

What you may be hearing as "*G'morning*" is likely just someone saying the word "good" so quickly that they are not enunciating clearly. I don't recall ever seeing the greeting *written* this way, but I may be wrong. "*G'day*" is a well known Australian greeting, so widely known that it is commonly written as shown here. I would say this is a case of the "D" in "good" blending into the "D" in "day" and over time becoming an accepted *contraction*. However the words "good" and "morning" do not naturally blend so easily, and while it may *sound* like someone is saying "g'morning" I don't believe it is a *recognised* contraction.

And of course, nobody ever says "*gafternoon*".

Comment: The "correct" greeting is "good morning" – unless it happens to be [after noon](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/is-it-ok-to-say-good-morning-at-anytime).

Comment: @J.R. the title of the question is "a morning greeting" so I took that as given. Still I've added it in for you.

Answer (score 1):

All of these are accepted spoken greetings of various levels of formality. "GOOD morning" (with the stress on "good") is a little unusual though, most likely to be spoken by a passive-aggressive prescriptivist responding to someone who just greeted them with "morning".

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is no comparison to "Good Morning", but the definition of formal has to change. Who would have imagined corporate offices filled with developers in tees and Cargos (Some people in suits still dislike it :D).
Coming back to our topic, unless you know whom you are greeting, it's safe to stick to good old "Good morning".
If it's a person you meet everyday and you guys are casual a morning also suffice.